# Как подменить тип исключения из прокси?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Если прокси перехватывает присваивание и не подтверждает его, то в строгом режиме кидается исключение `TypeError`. Но я тут пытаюсь использовать прокси не по назначению и мне надо от него в такой ситуации получть `ReferenceError`.

Как сделать, чтобы вторым результатом было `ReferenceError`?

```js
var code = `
  try {
    a = 1;
    console.log("Ok");
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.name);
  }
`;

var p = new Proxy({a:undefined}, {set(){}});

with (p) (function () {               eval(code); })(); // Ok
with (p) (function () { 'use strict'; eval(code); })(); // TypeError
         (function () { 'use strict'; eval(code); })(); // ReferenceError
```

PS: [Этот вопорс на английском.](//stackoverflow.com/q/46676709/4928642)